# How to troubleshoot poor trigram (gin) index performance?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a compound `LIKE` in a query that would have seemed to have benefited from a `gin` index however on two practically identical servers I see vastly different performance, with the worst case being almost as slow as a `Seq Scan`:

Bad:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nodes.node_path FROM nodes WHERE nodes.node_path LIKE 'company%/path%';
                                                                    QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on nodes  (cost=2114.03..17149.31 rows=3875 width=42) (actual time=11000.379..11036.533 rows=52 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((node_path)::text ~~ 'company%/path%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 46597
   Heap Blocks: exact=27913
   Buffers: shared hit=73481
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on nodes_node_path_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..2113.06 rows=3875 width=0) (actual time=10992.576..10992.576 rows=46649 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((node_path)::text ~~ 'company%/path%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=45568
 Planning time: 0.245 ms
 Execution time: 11036.769 ms
(10 rows)
```

Good:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nodes.node_path FROM nodes WHERE nodes.node_path LIKE 'company%/path%';
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on nodes  (cost=2528.05..20571.91 rows=4651 width=43) (actual time=1329.024..1354.603 rows=56 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((node_path)::text ~~ 'company%/path%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 48704
   Heap Blocks: exact=16106
   Buffers: shared hit=126080
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on nodes_node_path_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..2526.89 rows=4651 width=0) (actual time=1324.801..1324.802 rows=48760 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((node_path)::text ~~ 'company%/path%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=109974
 Planning time: 0.237 ms
 Execution time: 1354.748 ms
(10 rows)
```

For index:

```
CREATE INDEX nodes_node_path_gin_idx ON public.nodes USING gin (node_path gin_trgm_ops)
```

Where `node_path` stores slash delimited file paths.

These hosts otherwise exhibit very similar performance, and there's seemingly no disk I/O or other factors obviously different between these executions.

I enabled `track_io_timing`, `I/O Timings` is not emitted, and `BUFFERS` indicates `Buffers: shared hit=43783`. I dumped this column to a local 9.6.16 instance and it runs in milliseconds, but on the RDS Postgres 9.6.11 instance it's always 10 seconds:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT nodes.node_path FROM nodes WHERE nodes.node_path LIKE 'company%/path%';
                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on nodes  (cost=403.14..15246.51 rows=4018 width=42) (actual time=76.402..76.421 rows=52 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((node_path)::text ~~ 'company%/path%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 48576
   Heap Blocks: exact=506
   Buffers: shared hit=8530
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on nodes_node_path_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..402.13 rows=4018 width=0) (actual time=71.494..71.494 rows=48628 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((node_path)::text ~~ 'company%/path%'::text)
         Buffers: shared hit=8024
 Planning time: 0.188 ms
 Execution time: 76.452 ms
(10 rows)
```

How do I get information on where the cost is for the `Bitmap Index Scan` itself - I assume it's something specific to the implementation of the `~~` operator for the `gin` index type, but is there additional instrumentation I can enable to understand the unexplained time?

Comment: No IO at all it seems. `I/O Timings` is not emitted, `Buffers: shared hit=43783`.

Comment: Is it 43783 on both the fast server and the slow server?  Does "top" show you anything different between servers, maybe a high steal ("st") percentage?  I think my next step would to run `perf top -p <process pid>` on them.  You might want to run the queries in a tight loop to (in psql, you can end the command with "\watch 0.001" rather than than ";")  give perf enough time to collect enough samples.

Comment: Another thought, do they have the same versions of pg_trgm installed?

Comment: The fast server reads more blocks and has higher row counts, thus the confusion. Unfortunately they're RDS instances so I have less access than I'd like. Yes, same version of pg_trgm. Trying to reproduce on an instance I have more access to.

Comment: You should post the complete `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added complete plans with a single `LIKE` for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks. It would be particularly interesting to have the same for the slow execution.

Comment: @jjanes turns out that the `pg_trgm` version _was_ skewed. `1.1` on the slow instances `1.3` on the fast. Thanks for the pointers, please post an answer so I can accept. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substantial improvements were made to pg_trgm in PostgreSQL v9.6, pg_trgm v1.3.

But if you upgraded your server from before 9.6 to 9.6 or later using "pg_upgrade", you will not benefit from these improvements until you do `alter extension pg_trgm update TO "1.3"`.